# How can I tell if a bitmap has been rotated?

Tags: c#

I know in BitmapImage there is a Rotation method with is able to get and set the rotation of the BitmapImage, however for a Bitmap there does not seem to be a way to obtain the rotation changes that have been applied.

I have explored the object properties for the Bitmap and I don't seem to see any useful information that could help me obtain the rotation that has been applied.

I set the rotation using:

```
Bitmap rotatebmp = OriginalBitmapInfo[Page - 1].Bitmap;
rotatebmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
```

once I have applied the rotation, how can I then check to see what rotation actions have been applied to that bitmap ?

I have checked the PropertyItems

```
 PropertyItem[] propItems = DocViewer.OriginalBitmapInfo[0].Bitmap.PropertyItems;

 foreach (var prop in propItems)
 {

     var letsLook = prop;
 }
```

but there are no items so the rotation is not there.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just keep track of the operations you've applied yourself?

Comment: I could do that yes, but i was hoping that this information could be obtained from the Bitmap itself

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I don't see any indication of a memory of operations.

Comment: Yeah there's no way to get this information from the `Bitmap` object.

Comment: thanks all for your confirmation of this. I just ended up creating a BitmapInfo class and kept track of the rotation of pages instead. cheers